# Change only numbers' font of both text and math mode

Tags: fonts

I want to use the font [Fira Sans](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/firasansnewtxsf/) for my document, but this font has only "old-style" numbers. I was wondering if it was possible to change only the numbers' font so it would be different from the alphabetical characters.

I searched a lot but all answers I could find would only change the font in math mode using `\DeclareMathSymbol`, I want this modification to affect all the document.

Thank you.

PS: I realize I could just use another font which has regular numbers, but I want to know (no matter the extra work) if its feasible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I call `\usepackage[sfdefault,lining]{FiraSans}`, the numbers are lining.

Comment: And the opentype font supports at least 4 different styles of figures: oldstyle, lining, proportional and tabular (2x2). The `FiraSans` package also supports the 2x2 set of possibilities.

Comment: The solutions by @egreg sets the lining (proportional, ...) style of figures for the whole document. Is there an easy way to change the lining of the math mode only - to retain readability throughout the text, but align numbers within specific equations?

Comment: @tipavi In `unicode-math`, you can `\setmathfont[range=up/Digits, Numbers={Lining, Proportional}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Fira Sans}`. You could also try the experimental Fira Math font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an XY problem.  In LuaTeX or XeTeX, you can turn off old-style numbers with

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}

\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
```

Or `\usepackage[fira]{fontsetup}` might work.

In PDFTeX, load

```
\usepackage[lining, sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
```

to load Fira Sans with lining numbers as the default font, and Fira Mono as the matching monospace font.  You would also need to load a sans-serif math package, and set its letters and numerals to use the main text font with `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}`.

Answer (score 0):

With `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec` it's fairly easy :

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[]{Fira Sans}
\setmathrm[]{Anotherfont}
```

Or you could check your font and the doc of Fontspec to edit `\setmathrm[]{Fira Sans}` with the adequate options if it's available.