# Change Font of Numbers Using Baskerville

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am using the a Baskerville font, via

```
\usepackage{lmodern} % monospace font
\usepackage[scale=0.89]{tgheros} % Helvetica is too big
\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx} % tosf in text, tlf in math
\usepackage[baskervaldx,cmintegrals,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Baskervaldx
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
```

However, I'm not a fan of the numbers in `textmode`, but I am in `mathmode`. So I want to change the numbers to be in the maths format; this saves me from writing $1$ every time, but also citations and the bibliography would then use the maths format.

There are various related questions:

- [Change only numbers' font of both text and math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266157/change-only-numbers-font-of-both-text-and-math-mode);
- [Changing Number Font Into Sans Serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185172/changing-number-font-into-sans-serif);
- https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20600.

However, I have not been able to successfully adapt any of these answers into a solution for my problem.
I'd rather stick with `pdflatex` rather than `xelatex`... although I can't think of a rigorous justification for that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `osf` option to not have oldstyle figures in text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern} % monospace font
\usepackage[scale=0.89]{tgheros} % Helvetica is too big
\usepackage[]{Baskervaldx} % tosf in text, tlf in math
\usepackage[baskervaldx,cmintegrals,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Baskervaldx
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit

\begin{document}

1234567890


$1234567890$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well that was easy, thanks! +1 -- I got the Baskerville code from another question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241202/81928), and didn't understand what `osf` was. Thanks very much! (I'll accept once the time limit has passed...)